# java hibernate - how do i map a date column as datetime?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

In my sql there are the following date types: 
Date ,Time,Year, Datetime, timestamp.

my class holds a date object.
How can I choose which type should be created in the DB?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can mark the Date-object with @Temporal-annotation:

> In plain Java APIs, the temporal
>   precision of time is not defined. When
>   dealing with temporal data you might
>   want to describe the expected
>   precision in database. Temporal data
>   can have DATE, TIME, or TIMESTAMP
>   precision (ie the actual date, only
>   the time, or both). Use the @Temporal
>   annotation to fine tune that.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) 
private Date someDate;
```